# Verifying AD connectivity using Wildfly jboss-cli

Tags: jboss, active-directory, ldap, wildfly

I'm struggling with wildfly connectivity to an AD server, I could ping the server's machine, but when I tried to authenticate using it I get a:

> connection timeout exception.

that's why I'm trying to test the connectivity of wildfly to the server. 
So my question is : is there a way to test the connectivity of a wildfly server to an AD server (using jboss-cli for example ) ?